# i am learning springboot and try to create a table user (maven project)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, maven

i am using vs code , jdk version(19), windows 10, java 17 for springboot ,mysql ,hibernate ,lombok etc .
the project files are as follows;

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ijse</groupId>
    <artifactId>databseSpringboot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>databseSpringboot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties;

```
server.port=8089

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springbootdatabase
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password="1234"
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto =update
```

user.java;

```
package com.ijse.databseSpringboot.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    private String password;
}
```

App.java

```
package com.ijse.databseSpringboot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DatabseSpringbootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DatabseSpringbootApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

i have a database named 'springbootdatabase'. user ; root password; 1234
but when i run the App.java file the following error i occured;

```
2023-12-02T12:20:38.498+05:30  INFO 5012 --- [           main] c.i.d.DatabseSpringbootApplication       : Starting DatabseSpringbootApplication using Java 17.0.5 with PID 5012 (F:\CMJD\internet tec\springboot\databseSpringboot\databseSpringboot\target\classes started by user in F:\CMJD\internet tec\springboot\databseSpringboot\databseSpringboot)
2023-12-02T12:20:38.503+05:30  INFO 5012 --- [           main] c.i.d.DatabseSpringbootApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-12-02T12:20:39.442+05:30  INFO 5012 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-12-02T12:20:39.478+05:30  INFO 5012 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 20 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-12-02T12:20:40.317+05:30  INFO 5012 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8089 (http)
2023-12-02T12:20:40.327+05:30  INFO 5012 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-12-02T12:20:40.327+05:30  INFO 5012 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.16]
2023-12-02T12:20:40.459+05:30  INFO 5012 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-12-02T12:20:40.464+05:30  INFO 5012 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1872 ms
2023-12-02T12:20:40.690+05:30  INFO 5012 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-12-02T12:20:40.763+05:30  INFO 5012 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.3.1.Final
2023-12-02T12:20:40.809+05:30  INFO 5012 --- [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2023-12-02T12:20:41.101+05:30  INFO 5012 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-12-02T12:20:41.141+05:30  INFO 5012 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-12-02T12:20:42.450+05:30 ERROR 5012 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar:8.2.0]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar:8.2.0]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:815) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar:8.2.0]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:438) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar:8.2.0]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar:8.2.0]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:189) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar:8.2.0]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:424) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]     
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:273) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:223) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1432) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1503) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]        
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1822) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1] 
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1771) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]    
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]       
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1173) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:936) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]        
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:753) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:455) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1342) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1331) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at com.ijse.databseSpringboot.DatabseSpringbootApplication.main(DatabseSpringbootApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]

2023-12-02T12:20:42.477+05:30  WARN 5012 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException, String)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()" is null
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]    
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:273) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:223) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1432) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1503) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]        
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1822) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1] 
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1771) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]    
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]       
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1173) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:936) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]        
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:753) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:455) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1342) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1331) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at com.ijse.databseSpringboot.DatabseSpringbootApplication.main(DatabseSpringbootApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]

2023-12-02T12:20:42.487+05:30 ERROR 5012 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'javax.persistence.jdbc.url', 'hibernate.connection.url', 
or 'hibernate.dialect')
2023-12-02T12:20:42.487+05:30  WARN 5012 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'javax.persistence.jdbc.url', 'hibernate.connection.url', or 'hibernate.dialect')
2023-12-02T12:20:42.495+05:30  INFO 5012 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-12-02T12:20:42.507+05:30  INFO 5012 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-12-02T12:20:42.536+05:30 ERROR 5012 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata 
(please set 'javax.persistence.jdbc.url', 'hibernate.connection.url', or 'hibernate.dialect')
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1775) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]    
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]       
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1173) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:936) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]        
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:753) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:455) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1342) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1331) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at com.ijse.databseSpringboot.DatabseSpringbootApplication.main(DatabseSpringbootApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'javax.persistence.jdbc.url', 'hibernate.connection.url', or 'hibernate.dialect')
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:223) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1432) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1503) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1771) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]                                                                                                                    n.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'javax.persistence.jdbc.url', 'hibernate.[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]        connection.url', or 'hibernate.dialect')                                                                                                            .1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:190) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]jar:6.3.1.Final]                                                                                                                                    22) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1] 
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:86) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6 ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]    .3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentWithDefaults(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:141) ~[hiberconnection.url', or 'hibernate.dialenate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:344) ~[jar:6.3.1.Final]hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]                                                                                                         .3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1nate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Fina.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-6.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final].3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]                                                                                                                         Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at ....(more)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your password is `1234` instead of `"1234"` then it should be

```
spring.datasource.password=1234
```

Whatever the value is you need to put the exact value without `""` in your application.properties.

Comment: thank you very very much Mr. . coz i spent one week to solve this. the `""` is the error in my properties file.

Comment: No worries, thank you for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. add this line in application.properties

> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

2. also few more annotations in user.java model class to implement NoArgsConstructor, allArgsConstructor, Data, builder.
3. Make sure your given correct database name
4. Implement JPARespository interface to communicate with database